# how to toggle appended elements using multiple buttons and pass info to the output JQuery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, button, toggle

I have asked kind of a similar question before : [how to toggle using multiple buttons and pass info to the output JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898801/how-to-toggle-using-multiple-buttons-and-pass-info-to-the-output-jquery)

It was answered well, but this time I am using a different approach in the code thus  a new question. 
I am trying to toggle info and append a div using three different buttons.

Here is The code https://jsfiddle.net/YulePale/nruew82j/40/

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("brazil").addEventListener('click', function(e){
if(e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered) return;
e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered = true;
AppendFunction();

function AppendFunction() {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var homeTeam = document.getElementById("brazil").value
    para.innerHTML = 'This is the national team of ' + `${homeTeam}` + ':' 
   <br> <input type="text" value="${homeTeam}" id="myInput"><button 
   onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>';

        var element = document.getElementById("gugu");
    element.appendChild(para)
    }
})


document.getElementById("draw").addEventListener('click', function(e){
if(e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered) return;
e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered = true;
AppendFunction();

function AppendFunction() {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var homeTeam = document.getElementById("draw").value
    para.innerHTML = 'This two teams have played each other 4 times ' + 
`${homeTeam}` + ':' <br> <input type="text" value="${homeTeam}" id="myInput"> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>';

        var element = document.getElementById("gugu");
    element.appendChild(para)
    }
})


document.getElementById("russia").addEventListener('click', function(e){
if(e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered) return;
e.currentTarget.dataset.triggered = true;
AppendFunction();

function AppendFunction() {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var homeTeam = document.getElementById("russia").value
    para.innerHTML = 'This is the national team of ' + `${homeTeam}` + ':' 
<br> <input type="text" value="${homeTeam}" id="myInput"><button 
onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>';

        var element = document.getElementById("gugu");
    element.appendChild(para)
    }
})
```

PS: I don't know why the javascript code is not working in fiddle yet it is working on my computer.

If you look at the code I am basically trying to toggle a div with info on various teams. If it is Brazil the div comes with info on Brazil if Russia, info on Russia.
The problem with my current code is that it keep on appending the divs instead of 
toggling them. How can I toggle them? like this: https://jsfiddle.net/YulePale/7jkuoc93/

Instead of having them append another div each time I click a different button?
............................................................................................

**PS: EDIT & UPDATE:**

@Twisty, I forked the code from your fiddle and tried to implement it when working with more than one row of buttons. The code works well but I was unable to append a different and separate element for each row each time I click on a button on that row.

I tried putting the appended element as a class:
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/YulePale/a9L1nqvm/34/

Also tried putting it as an id:
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/YulePale/a9L1nqvm/38/

How can I put it in a way that each row appends it's own separate element and I would also like users to be able to copy using the copy button without the element disappearing. How do I make it in such a way that the element only disappears only when I click outside the respective:

```
<div class="col.buttonCol " id="buttons-div">
```

and also disappears when I click another row of buttons?
Also in your answer you said you would have used text boxes instead of appending this way. I checked the modals out and they all appear on the browser like alerts can you please point me to a resource that show how you can use a modal that works like an appending element instead of one that acts as an alert? Thank you.

Here is the link to the modals I saw: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: There are a number of reasons your code is not working in your Fiddle. First look at Line 9 in your JSFiddle. Also move your CSS to the Resources.

Comment: @Twisty I just updated the question, kindly check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted all your JavaScript to jQuery since you posted this in the `jquery-ui`, I am assuming you want to work with jQuery.

I will often organize my functions first and then the interactive actions.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function myFunction() {
    //Do Stuff
  }

  function AppendFunction(id) {
    var para = $("<p>");
    var home = $("#" + id).val();
    para.append("This is the national team of " + home + ":", $("<br>"), $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      value: home,
      id: "myInput"
    }), $("<button>").html("Copy Text").click(myFunction));

    $("#gugu").html(para);
  }

  function emptyOnDocumentClick(event) {
    var action = $(".triggered").length;
    $(".triggered").removeClass("triggered");
    return !action;
  }

  $("#brazil, #russia").on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("triggered")) {
      return;
    }
    $(this).addClass("triggered");
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    AppendFunction(myId);
  });

  $(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (emptyOnDocumentClick(e)) {
      $("#gugu").html("");
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nruew82j/91/

The basic concept here is a dialog and if it were me, I would use a dialog box either from BootStrap or jQuery UI. You're not doing that, so we're create the content and append it to a specific `<div>`. Then, like in your previous question, you just detect a click on the document and decide what that will do. In this case, I emptied the content of the `<div>` that we'd previously appended content to.

Hope that helps.